# How do i use AJAX to update my page after running a PHP function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, function

So i'm trying to make some text appear on my web page after a user clicks a button and runs a mysql function, but my AJAX function is only running the mysql function without doing anything else, i'm a little confused on what exactly i'm supposed to write to get it to update my page.

AJAX:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
                    var game = 69;
                    var review = 21;
                    $('#fav').click(function(){
                      $(document).load('core/like.php', {
                         thegame: game,
                         thereview: review
                        }); 
                    });
                    });</script>"
```

PHP (core/like.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    require 'connect.php';

    $thegame = $_POST['thegame'];
    $thereview = $_POST['thereview'];

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $datentime = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE reviews SET likes=likes+1 WHERE r_id='$thereview'");
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (l_id, username, r_id, date) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$thereview', '$datentime')");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt2->close();
    $conn->close();

    echo "<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>";
    exit();

} else {
    echo "<h1>ERROR</h1>";
} 

?>
```

Also, it only runs the mysql query when i use "document" as the jQuery selector. If i try and use a specific div like `$(#abox).load('core/like.php'..` it does nothing. If i try to add a selector at the end to specify what content from the php file i want to return like `$(document).load('core/like.php #content'..`, it also does nothing.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. You can check your browser's console to check the HTTP status code and response from the PHP script. Does the `#abox` element exist? Anything you can do to help provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem will be helpful.

Comment: @showdev am i not missing code? If i try and use ``#abox`` (which exists) then the function doesnt work at all and ignores the mysql stuff completely.

Comment: What indicates that the function doesn't work? Is the `click` handler firing? Do you see the `like.php` request in your browser's console?

Comment: @showdev ``echo "<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>";`` is not working. I also don't know why i have to use ``$(document)..`` as the selector for the mysql query to run.

Comment: Yes, you [should be able to use the `#abox` element](https://jsfiddle.net/z7d1q6Lp/). That's why I'm curious about the HTTP status code and response from the server, in order to troubleshoot. Note that in my example, I get a [201 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYVen.png) and can see the [data returned from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X7Tr.png).

Comment: @showdev how do i check the code? there are no errors in the console.

Comment: It depends on your browser. They are generally found in the "Network" tab. See [What are browser developer tools?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Comment: @showdev i'm using chrome. The status code for like.php is ``200 OK``

Comment: Ok, that's a good sign. What do you see in the "Network" tab under "Response"?

Comment: @showdev it says "this request has no response data available"

Comment: again, it only does that when i used the "document" selector. when i try to use the other div i get no response at all.

Comment: Ah, there might be a syntax error in the PHP script: `echo "<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>";` Notice that there's double quotes nested inside double quotes. Try single quotes for the outer ones: `echo '<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>';` Regarding using `#abox`, test that it exists with `console.log($('#abox').length);`.

Comment: @showdev alright after fixing that i'm now getting the ``<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>`` in the Response tab under Network. For the console log i'm getting ``1`` and another ``1``

Comment: `1` means that the element `#abox` was found in the DOM. But I'm not sure why it's outputting the number twice. It should be loading the response into that element [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/z7d1q6Lp/).

Comment: @showdev OH, it works now. It didn't work cause i didn't use quotes when adding the #abox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two problems:

1. There are nested double quotes in the PHP:
   `echo "<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>";`

   Use single quotes for the outer ones:
   `echo '<div id="content"><h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1></div>';`
2. Use quotes around the jQuery selector:
   `$(#abox).load('core/like.php'...`

   Like this:
   `$("#abox").load('core/like.php'...`

---

Also, please take serious note of the [comment about SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875923/how-do-i-use-ajax-to-update-my-page-after-running-a-php-function/56878124#comment100301578_56875923).